# Exporting Jar file trouble

Tags: java, eclipse, export, slick2d

Well, i decided to export my puny project, and see how everything is in an executable file. I then execute the file and nothing happens at all. No errors, no screen pops up all of a sudden, nothing. The program works beautifully in Eclipse, but works no other way. I have already tried the method of using Command prompt to execute the file, but it says "Error: unable to access jarfile Squarez.jar". I am using Slick2D and i hope this isn't the problem because it's an amazing library!

Comment: Try opening command prompt, `cd`ing to the directory it is located in, and then doing `java -jar Squarez.jar`.

Comment: @hichris123 Wow you reply fast! How do i "cd" to the directory in command prompt?

Comment: What is the directory your jar is in?

Comment: @hichris123 C:\Users\zoome_000\Documents

Comment: @hichris123 it's saying "The system cannot find the path specified" XD

Comment: Oopsie, forgot a 0. Try this: `cd C:\Users\zoome_000\Documents` and then `java -jar Squarez.jar`.

Comment: @hichris123 alright figured out the directory problem, the command prompt says "no main manifest attribute, in Squarez.jar".

Comment: Then you haven't made an executable jar.

Comment: @hichris123 now its saying "no lwjgl in java.library.path", I don' know what i'm doing wrong since it works in eclipse.

Comment: Create an executible jar from export in Eclipse.

Comment: @hichris123 I have, this executable jar is what is giving me problems.